# On Android, do I still need Power Lock if the device is connected to electricity?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have a Galaxy S3 as a test and development device. I stream audio and I use WiFi Lock. However it doesn't work for some of the users of other devices like "Sony Xperia S LT26".

I have contacted with the user and asked him if the power is connected to the device and if it is charging. I saw that even if the device is connected to power, it sleeps.. He said that when he turns off the screen, audio stops and he says this doesn't happen on 3G.

I can't replicate this issue. What can be the problem?

Comment: Yes you need it. There's an option in settings -> Development to never turn screen off while charging though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to programmatically set the screen to never turn off with :

```
params.flags |= LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
params.screenBrightness = 0;
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

That way you prevent the device to go into power-safe mode (sleep). About screenBrightness, you can set it to whatever you want.. I think that 100 is maximum brightness.

Comment: I have to let the screen turn itself "really" off while keeping Wifi "really" on during live streaming of audio.